# StringRelatedField not working as expected

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I have models,

```
class Reporter(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    reporter = models.ForeignKey(Reporter, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

and serializer,

```
class ReporterSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    article = serializers.StringRelatedField(source='article_set')

    class Meta:
        model = Reporter
        fields = '__all__'
```

and views

```
class ReporterAPI(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Reporter.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ReporterSerializer
```

Everything seems fine, but, my response showing something weird
response
Here is the [RESPONSE IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vNvdm.png)
The response **article** is showing wrong output

Answer (score 2):

Since `article_set` is list of objects you should add `many=True` argument:

```
class ReporterSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    article = serializers.StringRelatedField(source='article_set', many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Reporter
        fields = '__all__'
```